# How we choose deffacts from terminal in Jess rules

Tags: java, rules, jess

I have write my code in Jess which is:

```
;;;*************
;;;* MODULES   *
;;;*************

(defmodule EXAMPLE)

;;;*************
;;;* TEMPLATES *
;;;*************

(deftemplate EXAMPLE::status
(slot name)
(slot age)
)

;;;*************
;;;* FACTS     *
;;;*************

(deffacts EXAMPLE::?x
(status (name Peter)
    (age 24)
)
)

;;;***********************
;;;* GENERATE PATH RULES *
;;;***********************

(defrule EXAMPLE::rule1
    ?res <-
    (status (name Peter)
        (age 24)            
    )
    => 
    (printout t "Hello Peter" crlf)
    (restract ?res)
)

(run)
```

How do I call the rules with ?x from my terminal.

Because I would like find the fact with name ?x and search the rules only for this fact. I want my entry to be something like that (Peter) which Peter=?x .

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to either (1) use an explicit trigger fact, or (2) use a `defquery` instead of a `defrule` -- a query is a lot like a rule except you can invoke a query explicitly.

The first approach would look something like

```
(defrule EXAMPLE::rule1
    (greet ?x)
    ?res <- (status (name ?x))
    => 
    (printout t "Hello, " ?x "!" crlf)
    (retract ?res))


Jess> (assert (greet Peter))
<Fact-1>
Jess> (run)
Hello, Peter!
```

While the second would look something like this:

```
(defquery EXAMPLE::query1
    (declare (variables ?x))
    ?res <- (status (name ?x))))


Jess> (bind ?result (run-query* EXAMPLE::query1 Peter))
Jess> (while (?result next)
          (printout t "Hello, " (?result getString ?x) crlf)
          (retract (?result getObject res)))
```

You can read more about queries [here.](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/queries.html#queries)

Comment: Mr.Ernest thank you very much for your answer. Something more..and I will try to be more specific...if i have a 100 deffacts and i would like to "run" only the fact with the name "FirstFact" for my variable ?nameofFact which it will be given by (bind ?nameofFact (read)). My problem is how we could choose only the fact that we need...withour (reset) all the facts.